# Implement basic callback pattern in java, avoiding object creation

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, callback

I have implemented a very basic call back pattern in Android.
Below is my code

Interface:

```
public interface OnCustomEventListener{
    public void onEvent();   //method, which can have parameters
}
```

In class B

```
private OnCustomEventListener mListener; //listener field

//setting the listener
public void setCustomEventListener(OnCustomEventListener eventListener) {
   this.mListener=eventListener;
}
```

// When an event fires -

```
public void someEventFiringMethod(){
    mListener.onEvent();
}
```

and from class A -

```
classB.setCustomEventListener(new OnCustomEventListener(){
    public void onEvent(){
       //do whatever you want to do when the event is performed.
    }
});
```

This works pretty well and there is no issue, I however, feel there is a flaw with this design -
in this case -
class B defines the listener, which would mean that any class that wants to listen to the event has to create a new object of B and then has to call the method.
eg - from class A -->

```
B b = new B(); 
b.setCustomEventListener(this);
```

similarly from class D/class E

```
B b = new B(); 
b.setCustomEventListener(this);
```

Is there a way this can be avoided???

And also assume -> B could be dependent on several other objects and to create B this would only make it more complex for object creation of B

I know dagger 2 could be a solution to resolve dependency creation - but in my case, class B is an Adapter and class A is an Activity in Android. What would be the best solution to resolve the above case? Should I be injecting an adapter into an Activity - is that a good way to do so, I think not.

**Update --**

```
public class FoodItemRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodItemRecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<FoodItem> foodList;
    private OnFoodItemEnteredListener foodItemInterface;
    private Context mContext;
    private static final String TAG = "FoodItemRecyclerView";

    public FoodItemRecyclerView(List<FoodItem> foodList, Context context) {
        this.foodList = foodList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public interface OnFoodItemEnteredListener {
        void onFoodItemEntered(String foodItem, int position);
    }

    public void setInterfaceListener(OnFoodItemEnteredListener foodItemInterface){
        this.foodItemInterface = foodItemInterface;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FoodItemRecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final FoodItemRecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.edtFoodName.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)mContext.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(holder.edtFoodName.getWindowToken(), 0);
                foodItemInterface.onFoodItemEntered(v.getText().toString(),position);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return foodList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private EditText edtFoodName;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            edtFoodName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edtFoodName);
        }
    }

    public void notifyData(List<FoodItem> newFoodList) {
        this.foodList = newFoodList;
        notifyItemInserted(foodList.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

This is my class B, and the callback return to Activity class A, but what if I want the callback to return to the ViewModel? in this case I do not want to create a new object of adapter in my ViewModel class.

Comment: Please, post more information about class B. E.g., its responsibilities, is it singleton? Maybe, some piece of additional code will be useful

Comment: Moreover, I prefer to avoid creating instances via `new` since it can easily lead to tight couplings between views and non view classes

Comment: @Steyrix - please check my above code....what would you be suggesting in this case?

Comment: I suggest to use provider, which will know how to create your Adapter, and inject this provider into activity. Dagger2 can handle this for you. Or you can directly inject Adapter in Activity with dagger, since adapter is the part of view layer, it should not be a design flaw